# Is it possible to prove that (almost surely) a path of a scaled random walk does not converge to any function on $C[0,1]$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, random-walk

Consider the interpolated and scaled random walk generated by the independent random variables $(\xi_i)_{i \ge 1}$ with mean zero and finite variance:

$$ X^{(n)}_t := \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor tn \rfloor } \xi_i + (tn - \lfloor tn \rfloor )\xi_{\lfloor tn \rfloor +1}$$

There is the known *invariance principle* that states that $( X^{(n)}_t )_{t \ge 0}$ converges weakly to a Brownian motion.

> I have the following question: if one considers one path $ X^{(n)}_t(\omega)$ of $ X^{(n)}_t $, as $n $ increases, it seams that this path is continuously changing as an element of $C[0,1]$ (as a function in $t $) and thus never converges - except for the case when for some $N $
>
> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{i \ge N}^n \xi_i(\omega) \ \overset{n} \to 0 ,$$
>
> in which case it converges to the constant zero function.
>
> Is it possible to give a short argument that almost surely no path of $ X^{(n)}_t $ converges to any function in $C[0,1]$ in the metric $\sup_{0 \le t 1}\| \cdot \|$?

Most grateful for any help provided!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Kolmogorov or the Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law. Namely, if the limit of $X_t^n$ existed, it would be, thanks to any of these 0-1 laws, a nonrandom function. This would imply that $X_t^n$ converges to this nonrandom function also in law, contradicting the invariance principle.

Actually, it is possible to show that the closure of $\{X^n,n\ge 1\}$ is almost surely the whole $C_0[0,1]$.

I didn't find a reference to the fact, but here is a simple argument through the 0-1 law. Take a dense countable set $D\subset C_0[0,1]$ and let $\mathcal U$ be the collection of open balls centered at elements of $D$ with rational radii. It is not hard to see that for any $U\in \mathcal U$,
$$
A_U:=\{X^n \in U \text{ infinitely often}\} = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\{X^n\in U\}
$$ 
is stable under finite permutations of $(\xi_n,n\ge1)$. Therefore, by the Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law, $\mathrm P(A_U)\in \{0,1\}$. If $\mathrm P(A_U)=0$, then, using the portmanteau theorem and the Fatou lemma for probabilities, we get that
$$
\mathrm P(W \in U) \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathrm P(X^n\in U) \le  \mathrm P\Bigl(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\{X^n\in U\}\Bigr) = \mathrm P(A_U)= 0.
$$
This, however, contradicts the well-known fact that the support of the distribution of $W$ is $C_0[0,1]$. As a result, for any $U\in\mathcal U$, $\mathrm P(A_U)=1$. Since $\mathcal U$ is countable, this implies that 
$\mathrm P\left(\bigcap_{U\in \mathcal U} A_U\right)=1$, whence it easily follows that 
$$
\mathrm P\bigl(\text{the closure of }\{X^n\}\text{ is } C_0[0,1]
\bigr) = 1.
$$

---

Here is an explanation why $A_U$ is stable under finite permutations of $\xi_n$ for any $U\in \mathcal U$.

Let $U = B(f,q)$ with $f\in D$ and $q\in \mathbb Q\cap (0,\infty)$. There exists some $a>0$ such that $|f(x)|<q/2$ for $x\in [0,a]$. Set $\delta = \min(a,q/2)$.

Fix some $m\ge 1$. For $n> \delta^{-2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m|\xi_i|\right)^2$, $\max_{t\in[0,m/n]} |X_t^n|<\delta$. And if additionally $n\ge m/\delta$, then $$\max_{t\in[0,m/n]} |X_t^n - f(t)|\le \max_{t\in[0,m/n]} |X_t^n| +  \max_{t\in[0,\delta]}|f(t)| <q.$$
 Therefore, for such $n$, the fact $X^n\in U$ depends only on its values on $[m/n,1]$. However, permuting $\xi_1,\dots, \xi_m$ will not change the values of $X^n$ on $[m/n,1]$, implying the invariance of $A_U$ under any permutations of the first $m$ elements.

Comment: Thanks you! Could you please expand a little bit on how you apply the Kolmogorov or Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law? As I see it we would have that for any $n $, the set $\{n^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \xi_i \text{ converges }\}$ har probability 0 or 1 - and of course for any $n \neq m,  \{n^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \xi_i \text{ converges } \} = \{m^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \xi_i \text{ converges }\}$. May I conclude from this that for every $t $ we have that $\{X_t^{(n)} \text{ converges } \}$ has either probability  0 or 1?

Comment: @MrFranzén, no, this is not the reason. The reason is that the events $A_U$ do not change if you permute any finite number of $\xi_n$'s (so you can apply the Hewitt-Savage 0-1 law). Moreover, they do not depend on changes in any finite number of $\xi_n$'s, so you can apply the Kolmogorov 0-1 law.

Comment: Okey, but do the Kolmogorov and Hewitt-Savage 0-1 laws work for random elements of $C[0,1]$? I assume they do since you say so, but I have only seen them stated for $\mathbb R^d $ valued random variables.

Comment: The event $A_U$ is not about elements if $C[0,1]$, but about the random variables $\xi_n$.

Comment: Okey but please how would you show that $\limsup_n \{ \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor tn \rfloor } \xi_i + (tn - \lfloor tn \rfloor )\xi_{\lfloor tn \rfloor +1} \ \in U \}$ for any $n $ does not depend on the first $n $ elements, or that for any $n $ we may permute the $n $ first elements without changing the event?

Comment: @MrFranzén, actually, upon some thought, I found this wrong. The problem is when the subsequence of $X^n$'s inside $U$ "approaches its boundary". Then changing some finite number of $\xi_n$'s may drive (a tail of) this subsequence outside $U$. Despite it is possible to remedy the argument going through the Kolmogorov 0-1 law, much easier is to proceed via the Hewitt-Savage law; see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks I'm sort of seeing where you are heading, but I'm not able to understand this point about that given $U $ there should exist a $\delta >0 $ such that if $\sup_{t \in [0, \delta ]} |f (t)|< \delta$ then $ f \in U$.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{U}$ be the collection of all open balls, of rational radii, about polynomials with rational coefficients (and of course zero constant term). Then $\mathcal{U}$ is a countable basis for $C_0[0,1]$. Then given any basis element $B_\delta(p)$ and any $\delta>0$ take $a = \sup_{t \in [0,\delta]}p(t)$ and let $f $ be the linear function that goes from $0$ to $a + \delta$ on $[0,\delta ] $ - then $f $ furnishes a contradiction.

Comment: But maybe I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108122/discussion-between-zhoraster-and-mrfranzen).

Comment: Sorry to bother you more about this but I don't believe the implication $ n> \delta^{-2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m|\xi_i|\right)^2 \implies \max_{t\in[0,\delta]} |X_t^n|<\delta $ is ture, as the values that $X_t^{(n)}$ takes at $\delta$ (and to the left of it) depends on more and more $\xi_i $:s as $ n $ increases - thus it is not possible to put a bound on $ X_{t}^{(n)}$ in terms of $\sum_{i=1}^m \xi_i$, for $t $ and $m $ fixed and $n $ increasing.

Comment: You are right, but this probably does not matter: the event still does not depend on the permutation of $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_m$.

Comment: @MrFranzén, see the update, should be ok now.